# command line input case sensitivity

Tags: python, input, case

I am using command line inputs to do some simple tasks in my .py script.

My inputs are .py (GPIO) (SERIAL) (Log) (Debug)(Can Include an integer) (Pin)(Can include an Integer) (Verbose) (Help)

Of course it is all user input so it is case sensitive.

I am using:

```
if "gpio" in [x.lower() for x in sys.argv]:
```

which works fine and

```
if str(['Debug','10'])[1:-1] in str([sys.argv]):
if str(['Pin','10'])[1:-1] in str([sys.argv]):
```

Which works fine for Case Sensitive and exact integer value but fails for Case Sensitivity and different integer values.
So I need to make this accept any case str.lower() and any integer value int()
But everything I try fails. str.lower wont accept lists and I'm not sure what to do with integer.

I'd like to do this without importing a module if possible.

Comment: can you provide a [mcve] with something else than `sys.argv`, input & expected output?

Comment: Just drop the last requirement and use the `argparse` module and also don't accept case insensitive inputs.  And _please_ stop doing containment checks with (parts) of strings representations of lists. That's horrible.

Answer (score 1):

An example for `argparse`.  It isn't case insensitive but I see no point in allowing `--gpio`, `--Gpio`, `--gPiO`, …

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser


def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--gpio', action='store_true', default=False, help='Use GPIO.'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--serial', action='store_true', default=False,
        help='Make a serial connection.'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--log', action='store_true', default=False, help='Log actions.'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--debug', metavar='LEVEL', type=int, default=0, help='Debug level.'
    )
    parser.add_argument('--pin', type=int, help='Pin number.')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--verbose', action='count', default=0,
        help='Increase level of verbosity.'
    )
    options = parser.parse_args()

    if options.gpio:
        pass

    if options.debug > 0:
        pass

    if options.pin is not None:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You get a `--help` for free:

```
usage: test.py [-h] [--gpio] [--serial] [--log] [--debug LEVEL] [--pin PIN]
               [--verbose]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --gpio         Use GPIO.
  --serial       Make a serial connection.
  --log          Log actions.
  --debug LEVEL  Debug level.
  --pin PIN      Pin number.
  --verbose      Increase level of verbosity.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as BlackJack says, the correct way to do this is use argparse.  You can roll your own, but there's a reason argparse exists -- parsing gets complicated and the work has already been done.  Despite that here's a simple argument parser that will do what you want, assuming I understood your question:

```
import sys

cmd = None
commands = {}
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    # set the cmd for all the args that have a value
    if arg.lower() == 'debug' or arg.lower() == 'pin':
        cmd = arg
    # next check for boolean args
    elif arg.lower() == 'gpio':
        commands[arg.lower()] = True
    # take everything else to be a value associated with cmd
    else:
        commands[cmd] = int(arg)
        cmd = None
print(commands)
```

Comment: I am going to work on this and get back to you. I'm just a novice programmer.... I don't completely understand containment checks with parts of strings...

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing with Brad Dre's help "arg.lower() was:

```
  if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    for i in range(1,len(sys.argv)):
      if str.isdigit(sys.argv[i]):
        arg = sys.argv[i-1]
        newval[arg.lower()] = int(sys.argv[i])
```

Creating a "Dictionary" and then calling:

```
 if "debug" in newval:
 if "pin" in newval:
```

Worked out for me.

Comment: if my answer helped you should accept it and/or upvote it.  Also wanted to point out that if you follow my example carefully you can learn more idiomatic Python.  Your example looks like a javascript developer wrote it :-)